# Почему не работает работает \ перенос строки

Tags: javascript

В образце такой же пример переноса строки (только в теле кода, сохраняться значение должно в  строку) работает, а у меня нет, в чем причина?

```
var text = "lalala lalla \ 
 lalala lalala";

alert (text);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Уберите пробел после "\":

```
var text = "lalala lalla \
 lalala lalala";

alert (text);
```

Comment: Вот в чем дело, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Перенос на новую строку:

```
var text = "lalala lalla \n lalala lalala";
```

Output:

```
lalala lalla 
 lalala lalala
```

Запись в две строки:

```
var text = "lalala lalla \
 lalala lalala";
```

Output:

```
lalala lalla  lalala lalala
```

Comment: Да, этого я и добивался, проблема была в пробеле, спасибо!